# Is there a linear-time algorithm to determine if an array has duplicate entries that uses only constant extra space?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, arrays

Determining whether or not an array has duplicate entries has two straightforward solutions:

- Build a hashset of entries, then search for elements in this hashset. This takes $\mathcal O(n)$ time and $\mathcal O(n)$ extra space.
- Sort the array, then search for consecutive elements that are the same. This takes $\mathcal O(n \log n)$ time and $\mathcal O(1)$ extra space.

Is there an algorithm that can solve this problem with the best of both approaches, using only $\mathcal O(n)$ time and $\mathcal O(1)$ extra space?

Question [Finding duplicate in immutable array in linear time and constant space](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/95379/finding-duplicate-in-immutable-array-in-linear-time-and-constant-space) is similar, but the solution to that question only works when the values come from the set $\{1, ..., n\}$; my values are large integers. Also unlike that question, I allow the input array to be modified and used as a workspace.

One strategy might be to attempt to turn the array into a kind of hashtable. However, this seems like it won't work because of the lack of empty space (which makes both moving objects into place hard, as well as getting $\mathcal O(1)$ queries.).

However, I suspect that this cannot actually be done, but I'm not sure how to go about proving it.

Comment: The hashset method takes $\Theta(\log n)$ time. Hash table operations have $\log n$ cost, even if the constant is low in practice and they're often approximated as $O(1)$.

Comment: You can radix-sort array in place using MSD sort

Comment: And if you need fast practical approach, look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93563/fast-stable-almost-in-place-radix-and-merge-sorts

Comment: @Bulat A radix sort is still a sort, and takes $\log n$ time in the worst case. A radix sort can take $O(1)$ time if the elements are small integers (with a bound that doesn't depend on the array size), but the question explicitly rules this out (“my values are large integers”).

Comment: This "log n" is actually a log of value range. It's up to you how to count it, but at least I find your measurement non-standard and deletion of my answer unreasonable. If you don't agree with Wikipedia, use comments rather than moderation tools to promote your opinion

Comment: @Bulat It's not an opinion, it's a fact. Radix sort is only O(1) on a bounded range, and the question explicitly states that the range is not bounded. But regardless of the facts, your post did not answer the question, this is why I deleted it. If the question states “X does not solve the problem because …” and you want to answer “X actually does solve the problem because …”, you cannot leave out the “because …” part, it's absolutely essential.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that your elements come from a domain of size $n^2$. Any algorithm using time $T$ and space $S$ corresponds to a branching program having depth $T$ and containing at most $T \cdot 2^S$ nodes. Theorem 6.13 of [Time-space tradeoff lower bounds for randomized computation of
decision problems](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~beame/papers/randomts.pdf) shows that
$$
T = \Omega\left(n \sqrt{\log \tfrac{n}{S + \log T}/\log\log \tfrac{n}{S + \log T}}\right).
$$
In particular, if $S$ is $O(\log n)$ (which corresponds to your $O(1)$ extra space, *assuming you cannot modify the input*) then $T = \Omega(n\sqrt{\log n/\log\log n})$.

Comment: For elements from domain of P(n) size, hashing will take O(log(n)) time which contradicts to what he was said. No, it's time to delete your answer ;)

Comment: Hashing takes linear time. I don't follow.

Comment: If domain size is n^2, then element contains 2*log(n) bits, so its hashing requires O(log(n)) time. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: In the branching program model, querying an element is an atomic operation. It's an $n^2$-way branching program.

Comment: I.e. the program size is depends on the input size? In order to generate such program, you need O(n^2) time. If we can use O(n^3) branching as a single operation, we can choose proper branch based on the entire array contents, so "solving" problem in O(1) time.

Comment: Actually I find it's very strange idea to manipulate well-known measures of O(1) for element size, O(n) for hashing and radix sorting. Idea of reading log(n) bits in a single operation by declaring it as n-way branching is priceless!

Comment: You have a different program for every $n$. It's a non-uniform model.

Comment: I think it's going too far. Removing answer that relied on the standard fixed-size element assumption, but keeping answers with arbitrary non-standard assumptions made the entire topic meaningless. With only O(1) extra space, you can't even store one temporary data element of your size!

Comment: If the elements have fixed size, then the problem becomes very easy. In other words, keeping the elements fixed-size trivializes the problem and makes the entire topic meaningless.

Comment: My best assumption is that he doesn't know about in-place MSD sort.